# Atomikos XAResource raised 0: unknown

Tags: spring, hibernate, junit, jta, atomikos

I've setup JTA for our unit tests using:

- Atomikos (3.8)
- Hibernate (3.2.6/3.3.2)
- Spring (3.1)

After quite some effort I managed to get it up and running with a HyperSQL memory database, 2 XA Datasources and org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory for setting up a JNDI registry and the following jta.properties:

```
com.atomikos.icatch.enable_logging=true 
com.atomikos.icatch.service=com.atomikos.icatch.standalone.UserTransactionServiceFactory
com.atomikos.icatch.max_timeout=2000000
com.atomikos.icatch.log_base_dir=./
com.atomikos.icatch.output_dir=./
com.atomikos.icatch.console_log_level=DEBUG
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory
com.atomikos.icatch.tm_unique_name=transactionManager
```

In a unit test (class annotated to require a transaction) I create and fill the database with test data (before) and in the test I try to acquire a table listing.

However, after I have executed the first sql statement (schema, tables and data creation in 1 SQL statement) Atomikos seems to close my connections, preventing me to continue and get a list of the contents from the new table.
The exception states:

```
XA resource 'jdbc/loaniq/reader': resume for XID '7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657230303030313030303036:7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657231' raised 0: unknown
```

This also happens when I create the database and acquire the data in only one test method of this transactional Unit test.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208053/resume-for-xid-raised-0-unknown) suggests to add a test query to the datasource bean, how ever in this case this results in a infinite loop failing to find any working connection.

Hence my question: **How do I prevent Atomikos from closing by JDBCXAResource connections in the pool?**

Below some logging from the test showing that I was able to create the database, but afterwards can no longer use my datasource:

```
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: toString returning org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AbstractXPooledConnection     ] an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 1 context(s): returning proxy org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb
DEBUG 17:22:30 [ConnectionPool                ] atomikos connection pool 'jdbc/loaniq/reader': got connection from pool, new size: 14/15
DEBUG 17:22:30 [BaseTransactionManager        ] getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id transactionManager0000100006
INFO  17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: calling toString...
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: toString returning org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AbstractDataSourceBean        ] AtomikosDataSoureBean 'jdbc/loaniq/reader': returning org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb
DEBUG 17:22:30 [BaseTransactionManager        ] getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id transactionManager0000100006
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: notifyBeforeUse a SessionHandleState with 1 context(s)
DEBUG 17:22:30 [BaseTransactionManager        ] getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id transactionManager0000100006
DEBUG 17:22:30 [SessionHandleState            ] a SessionHandleState with 1 context(s): checking XA context for transaction com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp@6708d6d4
DEBUG 17:22:30 [CoordinatorImp                ] Coordinator transactionManager0000100006 entering state: ACTIVE
INFO  17:22:30 [CompositeTransactionImp       ] addParticipant ( XAResourceTransaction: 7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657230303030313030303036:7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657231 ) for transaction transactionManager0000100006
DEBUG 17:22:30 [XAResourceTransaction         ] XAResourceTransaction: 7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657230303030313030303036:7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657231: about to switch to XAResource org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAResource@17082d8
DEBUG 17:22:30 [XAResourceTransaction         ] XAResourceTransaction transactionManager0000100006transactionManager1: switched to XAResource org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAResource@17082d8
INFO  17:22:30 [XAResourceTransaction         ] XAResource.start ( 7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657230303030313030303036:7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657231 , XAResource.TMNOFLAGS ) on resource jdbc/loaniq/reader represented by XAResource instance org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAResource@17082d8
DEBUG 17:22:30 [TransactionContext            ] a TransactionContext: changing to state com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.BranchEnlistedStateHandler@19e733e
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: detected transaction com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp@6708d6d4
DEBUG 17:22:30 [CoordinatorImp                ] Coordinator transactionManager0000100006 entering state: ACTIVE
INFO  17:22:30 [CompositeTransactionImp       ] registerSynchronization ( com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy$JdbcRequeueSynchronization@6708d6d4 ) for transaction transactionManager0000100006
INFO  17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: calling prepareStatement...
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: prepareStatement returning org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement@1a0eec3[sql=[
CREATE SCHEMA LSUSER AUTHORIZATION SA
  CREATE TABLE "LSUSER"."VLS_CUSTOMER" 
   (    
   "CUS_CID_CUST_ID" CHAR(8), 
    "CUS_XID_CUST_ID" CHAR(15), 
    "CUS_NME_SHORT_NAME" CHAR(30), 
    "CUS_NME_FULL_NAME" VARCHAR(140), 
    "CUS_CDE_COUNTRY" CHAR(2), 
    "CUS_CDE_CUST_STAT" CHAR(5), 
    "CUS_IND_INVESTOR" CHAR(1), 
    "CUS_IND_BORROWER" CHAR(1), 
    "CUS_IND_GUARANTOR" CHAR(1), 
    "CUS_IND_BENEFIC" CHAR(1), 
    "CUS_IND_INTRL_ENT" CHAR(1), 
    "CUS_IND_RESTRICT" CHAR(1), 
    "CUS_CDE_BANK" CHAR(5), 
    "CUS_TSP_REC_CREATE" TIMESTAMP, 
    "CUS_TSP_REC_UPDATE" TIMESTAMP, 
    "CUS_UID_REC_CREATE" CHAR(8), 
    "CUS_UID_REC_UPDATE" CHAR(8), 
    "CUS_IND_SLG" CHAR(1), 
    "CUS_IND_MAJ_UNDWRT" CHAR(1), 
    "CUS_IND_CRA" CHAR(1), 
    "CUS_CDE_TRS_RPT_AR" CHAR(5), 
    "CUS_IND_SIMPLIFIED" CHAR(1), 
    "CUS_CDE_CUST_DESC" CHAR(5), 
    "CUS_CID_ULT_PARENT" CHAR(8), 
    "CUS_CDE_DEPT" CHAR(5), 
    "CUS_CID_IMM_PARENT" CHAR(8), 
    "CUS_CDE_EXPENSE" CHAR(15), 
    "CUS_CDE_PRIM_SIC" CHAR(10), 
    "CUS_CDE_PROSPECT" CHAR(5), 
    "CUS_CDE_LEGAL" CHAR(5), 
    "CUS_CDE_SIC_CNTRY" CHAR(2), 
    "CUS_CDE_BRANCH" CHAR(5), 
    "CUS_CDE_ORIGIN" CHAR(5), 
    "CUS_CDE_LANGUAGE" CHAR(5), 
    "CUS_IND_VAT_SUBJCT" CHAR(1), 
    "CUS_TXT_VAT_NUMBER" CHAR(15), 
    "CUS_AMT_OS_LIMIT" DECIMAL(31,3), 
    "CUS_CDE_OS_LIM_CCY" CHAR(3), 
    "CUS_IND_OS_LIM_ERL" CHAR(1), 
    "CUS_CDE_MASTER_ACT" CHAR(5), 
    "CUS_IND_BROKER" CHAR(1), 
    "CUS_CDE_DEP_SUBTYP" CHAR(5)
   )
]]
INFO  17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: isClosed()...
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: isClosed() returning false
DEBUG 17:22:30 [BaseTransactionManager        ] getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id transactionManager0000100006
INFO  17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: calling getWarnings...
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: getWarnings returning null
DEBUG 17:22:30 [BaseTransactionManager        ] getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id transactionManager0000100006
INFO  17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: calling clearWarnings...
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: clearWarnings returning null
DEBUG 17:22:30 [BaseTransactionManager        ] getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id transactionManager0000100006
INFO  17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: close()...
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AbstractConnectionProxy       ] Forcing close of pending statement: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement@1a0eec3[closed]
DEBUG 17:22:30 [SessionHandleState            ] a SessionHandleState with 1 context(s): entering notifySessionClosed
DEBUG 17:22:30 [SessionHandleState            ] a SessionHandleState with 1 context(s): delegeting session close to a TransactionContext
INFO  17:22:30 [XAResourceTransaction         ] XAResource.end ( 7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657230303030313030303036:7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657231 , XAResource.TMSUCCESS ) on resource jdbc/loaniq/reader represented by XAResource instance org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAResource@17082d8
DEBUG 17:22:30 [TransactionContext            ] a TransactionContext: changing state to com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.BranchEndedStateHandler@b5d05b
DEBUG 17:22:30 [TransactionContext            ] a TransactionContext: changing to state com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.BranchEndedStateHandler@b5d05b
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: closed.
DEBUG 17:22:30 [BaseTransactionManager        ] getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id transactionManager0000100006
DEBUG 17:22:30 [BaseTransactionManager        ] getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id transactionManager0000100006
INFO  17:22:30 [AbstractDataSourceBean        ] AtomikosDataSoureBean 'jdbc/loaniq/reader': getConnection ( null )...
INFO  17:22:30 [AbstractDataSourceBean        ] AtomikosDataSoureBean 'jdbc/loaniq/reader': init...
DEBUG 17:22:30 [BaseTransactionManager        ] getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id transactionManager0000100006
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AbstractXPooledConnection     ] an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 1 context(s): updating last time acquired
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AtomikosXAPooledConnection    ] an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 1 context(s): no test query, skipping test
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AtomikosXAPooledConnection    ] an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 1 context(s): creating connection proxy...
DEBUG 17:22:30 [SessionHandleState            ] a SessionHandleState with 1 context(s): notifySessionBorrowed
DEBUG 17:22:30 [TransactionContext            ] a TransactionContext: changing to state com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.NotInBranchStateHandler@98a8b8
DEBUG 17:22:30 [BaseTransactionManager        ] getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id transactionManager0000100006
INFO  17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: calling toString...
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: toString returning org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AbstractXPooledConnection     ] an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 2 context(s): returning proxy org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb
DEBUG 17:22:30 [ConnectionPool                ] atomikos connection pool 'jdbc/loaniq/reader': recycling connection from pool...
DEBUG 17:22:30 [BaseTransactionManager        ] getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id transactionManager0000100006
INFO  17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: calling toString...
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: toString returning org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AbstractDataSourceBean        ] AtomikosDataSoureBean 'jdbc/loaniq/reader': returning org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb
DEBUG 17:22:30 [BaseTransactionManager        ] getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id transactionManager0000100006
DEBUG 17:22:30 [AtomikosConnectionProxy       ] atomikos connection proxy for org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAConnectionWrapper@14492fb: notifyBeforeUse a SessionHandleState with 2 context(s)
DEBUG 17:22:30 [BaseTransactionManager        ] getCompositeTransaction()  returning instance with id transactionManager0000100006
DEBUG 17:22:30 [SessionHandleState            ] a SessionHandleState with 2 context(s): checking XA context for transaction com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp@6708d6d4
DEBUG 17:22:30 [CoordinatorImp                ] Coordinator transactionManager0000100006 entering state: ACTIVE
INFO  17:22:30 [CompositeTransactionImp       ] addParticipant ( XAResourceTransaction: 7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657230303030313030303036:7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657231 ) for transaction transactionManager0000100006
DEBUG 17:22:30 [XAResourceTransaction         ] XAResourceTransaction: 7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657230303030313030303036:7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657231: about to switch to XAResource org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAResource@17082d8
DEBUG 17:22:30 [XAResourceTransaction         ] XAResourceTransaction transactionManager0000100006transactionManager1: switched to XAResource org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAResource@17082d8
INFO  17:22:30 [XAResourceTransaction         ] XAResource.start ( 7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657230303030313030303036:7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657231 , XAResource.TMJOIN ) on resource jdbc/loaniq/reader represented by XAResource instance org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAResource@17082d8
WARN  17:22:30 [XAResourceTransaction         ] XA resource 'jdbc/loaniq/reader': resume for XID '7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657230303030313030303036:7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657231' raised 0: unknown
javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Invalid XAResource state
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAResource.start(Unknown Source)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction.resume(XAResourceTransaction.java:498)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.BranchEnlistedStateHandler.<init>(BranchEnlistedStateHandler.java:59)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.NotInBranchStateHandler.checkEnlistBeforeUse(NotInBranchStateHandler.java:65)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.TransactionContext.checkEnlistBeforeUse(TransactionContext.java:88)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.SessionHandleState.notifyBeforeUse(SessionHandleState.java:179)
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy.enlist(AtomikosConnectionProxy.java:208)
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy.invoke(AtomikosConnectionProxy.java:142)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:534)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getPreparedStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1577)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:696)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:312)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1723)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:65)
    at com.ing.liqmw.trade.dao.DataStubTest.test(DataStubTest.java:171)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
WARN  17:22:30 [JdbcConnectionProxyHelper     ] Error enlisting in transaction - connection might be broken? Please check the logs for more information...
com.atomikos.datasource.ResourceException: XA resource 'jdbc/loaniq/reader': resume for XID '7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657230303030313030303036:7472616E73616374696F6E4D616E6167657231' raised 0: unknown
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction.resume(XAResourceTransaction.java:505)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.BranchEnlistedStateHandler.<init>(BranchEnlistedStateHandler.java:59)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.NotInBranchStateHandler.checkEnlistBeforeUse(NotInBranchStateHandler.java:65)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.TransactionContext.checkEnlistBeforeUse(TransactionContext.java:88)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.session.SessionHandleState.notifyBeforeUse(SessionHandleState.java:179)
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy.enlist(AtomikosConnectionProxy.java:208)
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosConnectionProxy.invoke(AtomikosConnectionProxy.java:142)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy41.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Ps. adding Transactional Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW at method level, does not solve this. Basically the entire XA resource pool got disconnected...

Comment: I dropped the XA resource and started using a regular JDBCDatasource with connection pooling and 'CALL DATABASE_NAME()' test query.
This works fine on windows (except for the jndi stuff under linux :()

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced very similar problem with a JTA configuration consisting of:

- spring3.1.1.RELEASE,
- spring.batch 2.1.8.RELEASE,
- hibernate 3.6.6.Final
- atomikos 3.8.0
- hsqldb 3.2 6.

The exception:

```
javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Invalid XAResource state
   at org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAResource.start(Unknown Source)
   at com.atomikos.datasource.xa.XAResourceTransaction.resume( XAResourceTransaction.java:498)
```

has been thrown on the line 456 of the class `org.hsqldb.jdbc.pool.JDBCXAResource`

```
    if (state != XA_STATE_INITIAL && state != XA_STATE_DISPOSED ) {
        throw new XAException("Invalid XAResource state");
    }
```

At least in my use case the hsql XA driver seems to act too restrictive here. The sequence of the operations on the instance of JDBCXAResource
has been:
`start()`, `end()` and then again `start()` without prepare, commit or rollback in between.  This happens for instance if from the write method of spring batch, which
is transactional, transactional services are being called. This is the standard case
in our architecture and it works well with postgreSQL 9.1 in the place of hsqldb in the configuration above.

Because of that I tried to modify the line 456 of JDBCXAResource  to:

```
if (state != XA_STATE_INITIAL && state != XA_STATE_DISPOSED && state !=
XA_STATE_ENDED)  {
```

so that the state `XA_STATE_ENDED` is allowed in the `start()` operation as well. Our
tests work correctly with this change.

I do not know if this solution works generally correctly, but at least for tests it
may be sufficient.